# AppEngine URL Fetch Timeout

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Getting Errors when making URL Fetch calls to the Digital Ocean API.  When I use the remote API and make the same call everything is fine.

DeadlineExceededError: Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://api.digitalocean.com/images?api_key=XXXX&client_id=XXXX

Comment: Have you increased the deadline , the default is 5 secs I think,  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction

Comment: Yes but it doesn't seem to help.  If I run the fetch in development it comes back within a second.

Comment: Some sites rate limit by IP, and it's possible connections from appengine are being rate limited. You could try connecting via a proxy as a test to see if this is the case.

Comment: I would also log an issue with Digital Ocean or check if other users have experienced the same problem.

Comment: I moved the API call off of App Engine and it works fine so I'm guessing it is an App Engine problem since the error is intermittent.